# Ошибка терминала в phpStorm Node Js

Tags: phpstorm

Начал изучать Node Js. Установил пакет, через cmd всё работает. В phpStorm открываю терминал - он выдаёт следующее:

> Cannot open Local Terminal Failed to start [C:\Program
> Files\Git\bin\sh.exe -login -i] in E:/Учеба/NodeJs
>
> Error running process: CreateProcess failed. Code 2
>
> See your idea.log (Help | Show Log in Explorer) for the details.

В idea.log написано это:

> 2021-05-26 15:12:52,265 [ 665526]   INFO -
> rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project (name=NodeJs,
> containerState=ACTIVE, componentStore=E:\Учеба\NodeJs)
> MessDetectorBlackList took 11 ms
>
> 2021-05-26 15:12:52,892 [ 666153]   INFO -
> ndex.PrebuiltIndexProviderBase - Using prebuilt id-index from
> C:\Users\Олег\AppData\Local\JetBrains\PhpStorm2020.1\index.persistent\prebuilt\JavaScript\id-index.input
>
> 2021-05-26 15:14:09,165 [ 742426]   INFO -
> j.ide.actions.RevealFileAction - Exit code 1

Что делать?

Answer (score 0):

Полпробуйте обернуть путь к shell в кавычки (см. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-136139#focus=Comments-27-1422182.0-0). Или проапдейтите PhpStorm до последней версии

Comment: ничего не помогло